# Why my UniqPtr objects are double in size compared to std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

In real applications I should stick to the standard library facilities, for practice and understanding how those facilities work I should try to implement my own.

Here I've implemented a simulation of the smart pointer `unique_ptr`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <memory>


template <typename T>
class DefDel
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void operator()(U* p)const
    {
        std::cout << "freeing memory...\n";
        delete p;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class DefDel<T[]>
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    void operator()(U* p)const
    {
        std::cout << "freeing memory of an array of objects...\n";
        delete[] p;
    }
};

template <typename T, typename D = DefDel<T>>
class UniqPtr final
{
public:
    UniqPtr(T* = nullptr, D = DefDel<T>{});
    UniqPtr(UniqPtr const&) = delete;
    UniqPtr(UniqPtr&&) noexcept;
    UniqPtr& operator =(UniqPtr const&) = delete;
    UniqPtr& operator =(UniqPtr&&) noexcept;
    ~UniqPtr();
    T& operator*();
    T const& operator*() const;
    T* operator->();
    T const* operator->() const;
    operator bool() const;

private:
    T* ptr_{nullptr};
    D del_{};
};

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::UniqPtr(T* p, D del) :
    ptr_(p),
    del_(del)
{}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::UniqPtr(UniqPtr&& rhs) noexcept :
    ptr_(std::move(rhs.ptr_)),
    del_(std::move(rhs.del_))
{
    rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>& UniqPtr<T, D>::operator = (UniqPtr&& rhs) noexcept
{
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
        ptr_ = std::move(rhs.ptr_);
        del_ = std::move(rhs.del_);
        rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::~UniqPtr()
{
    del_(ptr_);
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T& UniqPtr<T, D>::operator*()
{
    return *ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T const& UniqPtr<T, D>::operator*() const
{
    return *ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T* UniqPtr<T, D>::operator->()
{
    return ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T const* UniqPtr<T, D>::operator->() const
{
    return ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::operator bool() const
{
    return ptr_;
}

// for array
template <typename T, typename D>
class UniqPtr<T[], D> final
{
public:
    UniqPtr(T* = nullptr, D = DefDel<T[]>{});
    UniqPtr(UniqPtr const&) = delete;
    UniqPtr(UniqPtr&&) noexcept;
    UniqPtr& operator =(UniqPtr const&) = delete;
    UniqPtr& operator =(UniqPtr&&) noexcept;
    ~UniqPtr();
    T& operator*();
    T const& operator*() const;
    T* operator->();
    T const* operator->() const;
    operator bool() const;

private:
    T* ptr_{nullptr};
    D del_{};
};

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T[], D>::UniqPtr(T* p, D del) :
    ptr_(p),
    del_(del)
{}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T[], D>::UniqPtr(UniqPtr&& rhs) noexcept :
    ptr_(std::move(rhs.ptr_)),
    del_(std::move(rhs.del_))
{
    rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T[], D>& UniqPtr<T[], D>::operator = (UniqPtr&& rhs) noexcept
{
    if(this != &rhs)
    {
        ptr_ = std::move(rhs.ptr_);
        del_ = std::move(rhs.del_);
        rhs.ptr_ = nullptr;
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T[], D>::~UniqPtr()
{
    del_(ptr_);
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T& UniqPtr<T[], D>::operator*()
{
    return *ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T const& UniqPtr<T[], D>::operator*() const
{
    return *ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T* UniqPtr<T[], D>::operator->()
{
    return ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
T const* UniqPtr<T[], D>::operator->() const
{
    return ptr_;
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T[], D>::operator bool() const
{
    return ptr_;
}


int main()
{

    UniqPtr<int[]> upi(new int[3]{57});
    std::cout << sizeof(upi) << '\n';
    std::unique_ptr<int[], DefDel<int[]>> upi2(new int[3]{57});
    std::cout << sizeof(upi2) << '\n';
}
```

- Why the size of my `UniqPtr` objects are double in size as `std::unique_ptr` (even being initialized with the same values)?
- Is that because of my class is storing a `Del_` object as a member?
- If that is the problem then how could I achieve the very similar behavior as `unique_ptr` with 0 cost?

Comment: Any reason why you cannot use a debugger to inspect both your objects and a sample `unique_ptr` instance, compare their internal layout, and see where the differences lie? This is something that you should be able to determine by yourself, after all this is one of the things that debuggers are for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Do you think my class is a bit good?

Comment: I don't know what "good" means. It's a template class. I see nothing that's ill-formed, to a first glance. If it's good enough for a C++ compiler, it's good enough for me.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Thank you. I meant whether there are some bad or mistakes in it.

Comment: The only design issue that I see is that having the deleter class as a class member accomplishes absolutely nothing useful, whatsoever except, perhaps, as you suspect it makes the size of the class bigger. Any code in the unique class that needs to reference the code from the deleter can simply reference the class itself, and the deleter class itself can be an ordinary template function.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: So how can I avoid storing it as a member?

Comment: Could you use [empty base optimazation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ebo)?

Comment: `std::unique_ptr` supports deleter with state. You can do funny stuff with this. Like instead of destroying the object, you can add the pointer to list known by the deleter-object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why the size of my UniqPtr objects are double in size as std::unique_ptr (even being initialized with the same values)?
> Is that because of my class is storing a Del_ object as a member?

Yes.
Because `D del_` needs to have storage, and every `T* ptr_` has to be properly aligned

> If that is the problem then how could I achieve the very similar behavior as unique_ptr with 0 cost?

You can privately derive from `D`, rather than have it be a member. Then an instantiation with an empty class may cave it occupy no extra storage.

```
template <typename T, typename D = DefDel<T>>
class UniqPtr final : D
{
public:
    UniqPtr(T* = nullptr, D = {});
    UniqPtr(UniqPtr const&) = delete;
    UniqPtr(UniqPtr&&) noexcept;
    UniqPtr& operator =(UniqPtr const&) = delete;
    UniqPtr& operator =(UniqPtr&&) noexcept;
    ~UniqPtr();
    T& operator*();
    T const& operator*() const;
    T* operator->();
    T const* operator->() const;
    operator bool() const;

private:
    T* ptr_{nullptr};
};

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::UniqPtr(T* p, D del) :
    D(del),
    ptr_(p)
{}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::UniqPtr(UniqPtr&& rhs) noexcept :
    D(std::move(*rhs)),
    ptr_(std::exchange(rhs.ptr_, nullptr))
{}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>& UniqPtr<T, D>::operator = (UniqPtr&& rhs) noexcept
{
    using std::swap;
    swap(static_cast<D&>(*this), static_cast<D&>(rhs));
    swap(ptr_, rhs.ptr_);
}

template <typename T, typename D>
UniqPtr<T, D>::~UniqPtr()
{
    static_cast<D&>(*this)(ptr_);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. would you add some suggested code please?